# Can you make mongo $text perform a logical AND search on multiple terms?

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way of making the following query return documents where the event value contains both "men" AND "final".

```
db.events.find( { $text: { $search: "men final" } } )
```

So "Men's Quarter Final" would match but "Women's Quarter Final" would not match?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may use a regular expression.

```
db.events.find({"name": /.*men.*final.*/i})
```

Note the i in the end. It ignores the case (Uppercase and Lowercase).

In the case you want to only select events that have Men's Final and not Women's final:

```
db.events.find({"name": /.*[^wo]men.*final.*/i})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below, this should return documents where the name contains both words "men" and "final". The \" creates a phrase rather than a sequence of words ORed together. A phrases forces a logical AND.

```
db.events.find({$text : {$search:"\"men\" \"final\""}});
```

Comment: This nearly works. I get results for women as well as men preumably because the word "women" contains the string "men"? Is the only way around that to put spaces either side of the search word - $search:"\" men \" \" final \"" ?